# Laravel middleware logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

I want to make a middleware in my Laravel 9 project where if the user is inactive, they automatically get logged out. In my middleware class, like the following.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->is_active != 1) {
        return Auth::logout();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But when I try it, I get an error like this.

[image: error laravel]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The logout function will not return the object, and you can't redirect it from middleware.**

What you can do is

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_active != 1) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login'); # add you login route
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, just some minor changes are needed.

So the problem is that your middleware would usually return the `$next($request);`, otherwise it would break Laravel's internal pipeline (You can read this good blog post to understand more about middleware and pipelines [Understanding Laravel Pipelines](https://jeffochoa.me/understanding-laravel-pipelines)).

But returning that will probably not work in your case since your `auth` middleware must have already been executed before this.

The easiest way to handle this would be to logout and abort (Assuming that returning a 401 response is what you would like in this scenario), something like

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->is_active != 1) {
        Auth::logout();
        abort(401, 'User is not active');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```